# Dual Boot Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: boot

Is it possible to install Windows 7 64-bit, then somehow install Windows Server 2008 R2 as a second OS, a dual boot situation, then on start up, choose which OS to boot into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you already have Windows 7 installed and you install Windows Server 2008 R2 on another disk or partition, the setup will take care *automatically* of configuring dual boot.